# 2001 Nissan Pathfinder - What other years have interchangeable body parts?

Tags: nissan, pathfinder, part-interchange

I need to replace the hood, front bumper, front light assemblies, etc. What years are interchangeable with the 2001 so I know what to look for in the junk yards?

Answer (score 2):

Your 2001 year model belongs to [Second Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Pathfinder) (1995–2004) of Nissan Pathfinders. So majority of parts should be the same for those years.

However, Wikipedia also mentions that there were minor facelifts on 1999.5 and 2001 models. So 1999.5-2001 would be a better guess if you want to take parts from exactly identical vehicles.

Also, there are websites that sell auto parts, like Amazon.com and Ebay.com. They have a compatibility check tool that will indicate whether "This Part fits your 2001 Nissan Pathfinder". Now if you register 3 cars on those websites, like:

1. 1995 Nissan pathfinder
2. 2004 Nissan Pathfinder
3. 2001 Nissan Pathfinder

And it says that the part (e.g. Front bumper or front light assembly) is compatible with all 3 year models, then you can buy the part. If it says that part is not compatible with at least one of the years, for example, due to facelift changes, then try to narrow down the year in which Nissan introduced this incompatibility by registering few more cars with different years.

*As Paulster2 indicated there is a possibility that Amazon or Ebay compatibility database is sometimes inaccurate. From my past experience it is very accurate when it comes to buying OEM parts. By the way in junkyards you will be getting OEM parts or parts that are verified to be OEM part compatible. Most often those compatibility check tools fail if you buy new non-OEM part that seller on Amazon or Ebay has not properly verified to be compatible with particular vehicle.*

Comment: What do you mean sign up on amazon and register?

Comment: @richard - At the top of the Amazon.com web page when looking for part, you can plug in your vehicle information and it will tell you if the part you are looking at is compatible with your vehicle. This works most of the time, but it's not foolproof. eBay does this as well. You put the vehicle in your "garage" on the site.

Comment: @richard I changed wording that tries to explain better on how you could use the Amazon and Ebay compatibility check tool. You can still use their compatibility check tools even without buying parts from them.